# Functionality for admin to log in in as user in Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5

Building an app in Laravel 5.3, one of the functionalities is for the admin to be able to log into the app as a user, to be able to see what that specific user can see, while maintaining his admin session to be able to go back to the user list and be possible to log in as another user without having to re-authenticate.

Currently implemented the basic out-of-the-box Laravel Auth, meaning if I start another auth session it will terminate my admin session making me having to re-login.

I have checked Laravel Multi Auth but seems to work with two tables (user,admin), which in my case we use one user table and use an ACL for managing roles and deciding whos admin and whos user.

What programming logic ideas do you guys have for this solution? Trying to find other opinions/ideas in how this could be implemented in Laravel 5.x

Comment: Did you find any solutions that fulfill your need?

Comment: @MunnaKhan yes, but I can't remember to the top of my head what the package is called, and I don't have access to that project anymore as I've switched companies. But there are several packages out there, one of them is Impersonate.

Answer (score 3):

I've implemented the feature on a project recently. I did this using the session and a middleware. This is how I did it:

1. Create a controller 'ImpersonateController' and Set two routes for `impersonateIn` and `impersonateOut` for the purpose.

   ```
   Route::get('impersonateIn/{user}', 'ImpersonateController@impersonateIn');
   Route::get('impersonateOut', 'ImpersonateController@impersonateOut');
   ```
2. In the `ImpersonateController@impersonateIn` method just set the user id you want to log in and the URL backUrl into the session variable.

   ```
   public function impersonateIn($id)
   {
       session(['impersonated' => $id, 'backUrl' => \URL::previous()]);

       return redirect()->to('dashboard');
   }

   public function impersonateOut()
   {

       $back_url = Request::session()->get('backUrl');

       Request::session()->forget('impersonated', 'secretUrl');


       return $back_url ? 
           redirect()->to($back_url) : 
           redirect()->to('dashboard');
   }
   ```

The first part is done. Now every request need to check the if the session has the 
`impersonated` variable set. A good place to do that is a middleware.

3. Create a middleware to check the session on the handle method. If the `impersonated` found then log as the user using the `Auth::onceUsingId()` for the current request only.

   ```
   class ImpersonateMiddleware
   {
       public function handle($request, Closure $next)
       {
           if(Request::session()->has('impersonated'))
           {
               Auth::onceUsingId(Request::session()->get('impersonated'));
               }

        }
   }
   ```
4. Now you just need to apply the middleware for every request. The best place to do this from the *Http/Kernel.php*

   ```
   protected $middlewareGroups = [

       'web' => [

           //....

          \App\Http\Middleware\ImpersonateMiddleware::class,
       ],
   ];
   ```
5. The only remaining thing is you need to check the session and replace the **logout** route to the `impersonateOut`. Now when the admin logged out from the user will be redirected to the old route. 
   That's it!

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you really have to login?
I would stay logged in as admin and simulate user login. 
You can allow admin access to all the databases.
In your controller you can use `User::find($user_id)` instead of `Auth::user()` for accessing user's data.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/database

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent

Comment: Hmm, sounds interesting. Thing is, page uses some big queries concerning the user ID at Auth object to show products, this would require a lot of programming changes and conditions to simulate a user compared to having 2 sessions (admin,user) and the system just naturally working with that session....My thoughts, but I'm looking into it.

Answer (score -1):

Personaly, I would do this with sessions. I have not used Laravel but I use PHP often, so my answer will be in PHP.
In the header page, you most likely have some kind of session check to see if the user is logged in. For example:

```
<? php
 session_start();
 if (isset($_SESSION['user'])){
 //do stuff with the user session
 } else {
 die('User not logged in!');
 }
 ?>
```

I would change this to something like:

```
<? php
 session_start();
 if (isset($_SESSION['fakeuser'])){
 //do stuff with the user session
 //change logout button to destroy this session instead of logging the user out
 }
 elseif (isset($_SESSION['user'])){
 //do stuff with the user session
 } else {
 die('User not logged in!');
 }
 ?>
```

In the page in which you swap users, you would just simply copy the way a session starts when a user logs in. To switch users, you destroy the new 'fakeuser' and you are back to your old session + admin permissions without having to log back in again.

That's the logical approach I would take anyways.